Azure text to speech python SDK timeout error
I have a minimal azure text to speech example which fails on some computers and not others. All of the computers are MacOS 14.5 running python 3.11.8 with azure-cognitiveservices-speech==1.41.1  there are no other differences between the computers running the code.
Some computers work instantly and produce an audio file, others never work and timeout with the following errors:
Error details: USP error: timeout waiting for the first audio chunk
Error: File:/Users/runner/work/1/s/external/azure-c-shared-utility/pal/ios-osx/tlsio_appleios.c Func:tlsio_appleios_destroy Line:196 tlsio_appleios_destroy called while not in TLSIO_STATE_CLOSED.
There is an open issue on github, although that only references the TLS error which I suspect secondary: https://github.com/azure/azure-c-shared-utility/issues/658
def text_to_speech(text, voice_name='zh-CN-YunfengNeural')

    if not os.path.exists(TEMP_AZURE_AUDIO_PATH): os.makedirs(TEMP_AZURE_AUDIO_PATH)
    output_file = os.path.join(TEMP_AZURE_AUDIO_PATH, f"{text[:10]}--{voice_name}--{style}.wav")

    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=credentials.azure_speech_key, region=credentials.azure_service_region)  
    speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = voice_name
    
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(filename=output_file)

    synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
    result = synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()

    # Check result status
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
        logger.info("Speech synthesis completed.")
        # Verify that the file was created successfully
        if os.path.exists(output_file):
            print(f"File '{output_file}' was created successfully.")
        else:
            print(f"File '{output_file}' was not created.")
            return None
        
    elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
        print(f"Speech synthesis canceled: {cancellation_details.reason}")
        if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
            if cancellation_details.error_details:
                print(f"Error details: {cancellation_details.error_details}")
        return None

    return output_file

Expecting with the same environment, os, python packages and same credentials that it would work on every computer. 5 out of 8 computers produce the error, the others work every time.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

I can see the output in the Windows like this.

Thanks all for your help with this. In the end it was actually a network issue which was really hard to debug, and so stackoverflow friends didn't have all the info - sorry!
Th actual solution: All of the computers run the the same VPN, but it turns out MSS clamping was not enabled on some routers, which meant the VPN dropped packets. Strangely, all other network activities worked fine, it just caused an issue with the Azure TTS API - weird!
(MSS Clamping is a network setting that adjusts the Maximum Segment Size (MSS) of TCP packets to ensure they fit within the limits of your network path, especially when using tunnels like VPNs.)

Below is the complete modified code to fix the error in two ways .

If the SDK method times out or fails, the code automatically falls back to the REST API for speech synthesis, ensuring that network or TLS-related issues with the SDK don’t block functionality.

The try-except block catches exceptions early, logs the issue, and switches to the REST API, ensuring smooth execution despite network or SDK issues.


Code :
import os
import logging
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import requests

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

AZURE_SPEECH_KEY = "<speech_key>"
AZURE_SERVICE_REGION = "<speech_region>"
TEMP_AZURE_AUDIO_PATH = "./azure_audio_output"

def text_to_speech(text, voice_name='zh-CN-YunfengNeural'):
    if not os.path.exists(TEMP_AZURE_AUDIO_PATH):
        os.makedirs(TEMP_AZURE_AUDIO_PATH)

    output_file = os.path.join(TEMP_AZURE_AUDIO_PATH, f"{text[:10]}-{voice_name}.wav")
    try:
        speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=AZURE_SPEECH_KEY, region=AZURE_SERVICE_REGION)
        speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = voice_name
        audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(filename=output_file)

        synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
        result = synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()

        if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
            print("Speech synthesis completed.")
            if os.path.exists(output_file):
                print(f"File '{output_file}' created successfully.")
            else:
                print("File not created.")
                return None

        elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
            print(f"Synthesis canceled: {result.cancellation_details.reason}")
            if result.cancellation_details.error_details:
                print(f"Error details: {result.cancellation_details.error_details}")
            return None
        return output_file

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception occurred: {e}")
        print("Attempting to use REST API fallback...")
        return text_to_speech_rest(text, voice_name)

def text_to_speech_rest(text, voice_name='zh-CN-YunfengNeural'):
    url = f"https://{AZURE_SERVICE_REGION}.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1"
    headers = {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': AZURE_SPEECH_KEY,
        'Content-Type': 'application/ssml+xml',
        'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat': 'riff-24khz-16bit-mono-pcm'
    }
    ssml = f"""
    <speak version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'>
        <voice xml:lang='zh-CN' name='{voice_name}'>
            {text}
        </voice>
    </speak>"""

    try:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=ssml.encode('utf-8'))
        if response.status_code == 200:
            output_file = os.path.join(TEMP_AZURE_AUDIO_PATH, f"{text[:10]}-{voice_name}-rest.wav")
            with open(output_file, "wb") as audio_file:
                audio_file.write(response.content)
            print(f"REST API: File '{output_file}' created successfully.")
            return output_file
        else:
            print(f"REST API Error: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"REST API exception: {e}")
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = "你好, 欢迎使用微软的语音服务。"
    voice_name = "zh-CN-YunfengNeural"
    output = text_to_speech(text, voice_name)

    if output:
        print(f"Audio file generated: {output}")
    else:
        print("Failed to generate audio.")

Output :
The following code ran succesfully and got the speech output from text input as shown below.


Unfortunately I get the same response whether using the SDK or the REST API. However, appreciate your help, this did help me to debug further, I've discovered their is a difference between the machines which is the open SSL version, it seems like newer than Jan 2024 version of openSSL 3 causes this issue.  I use the same pre-built version of python on each machine, but it seems like the open ssl versions are different (https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.8/python-3.11.8-macos11.pkg). Any ideas on when MS will update to latest open ssl version?

It seems like OpenSSL version compatibility is the key issue, try downgrading OpenSSL.
